# CAShapeLayer stroke animated with CADisplayLink not completed

Tags: swift

I have set up a `CADisplayLink` that calls the following `drawCircle()` function to draw a circle path animation in 10 seconds:

```
func drawCircle() {
    currentDuration = currentDuration + displayLink.duration
    circleLayer.strokeEnd = min(CGFloat(currentDuration/maxDuration), 1)

    if (currentDuration >= maxDuration) {
        stopCircleAnimation()
    }
}

func stopCircleAnimation() {
    let pausedTime = circleLayer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), fromLayer: nil)
    circleLayer.speed = 0
    circleLayer.timeOffset = pausedTime
}
```

where `currentDuration` is the elapsed time, and `maxDuration` is equal to 10. This works fine, except when `currentDuration >= maxDuration`. Even though the strokeEnd is set to 1, it never fully completes the circle. Why is this??

EDIT

I think it could have something to do with the `speed` property of the `circleLayer`. If I set it to a higher amount, e.g. 10, then the circle is completely closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that setting the `strokeEnd` of your `CAShapeLayer` generates an implicit animation to the new value. You then set the layer's speed to zero before this animation is complete, therefore 'pausing' the animation, so that it appears 'incomplete'.

While you can work around by disabling implicit animations through `setDisableActions` – you should probably be considering if using a `CADisplayLink` is really appropriate here. Core Animation is designed to generate and run animations for you in the first place by generating its own intermediate steps, so why not achieve the same result with an explicit or implicit animation of your layer's `strokeEnd`?

Here's an example of how you could do this with an implicit animation:

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(10)

// if you really want a linear timing function – generally makes the animation look ugly
CATransaction.setAnimationTimingFunction(CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear))

circleLayer.strokeEnd = 1
CATransaction.commit()
```

Or if you want it as an explicit animation:

```
let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
anim.fromValue = 0
anim.toValue = 1
anim.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
anim.duration = 10
circleLayer.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "strokeEndAnim")

// update model layer value
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
circleLayer.strokeEnd = 1
CATransaction.commit()
```

Comment: Actually I need to use the CADisplayLink because I'm using it in conjunction with timing for a video, so need it to be as precise as possible. However, you are right about disabling the CATransaction actions (as I found out before you posted your answer). I will accept your answer though because you went into detail.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer – disable animations when setting the strokeEnd property:

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
circleLayer.strokeEnd = min(CGFloat(currentDuration/maxDuration), 1)
CATransaction.commit()
```